# Uniqueness of sum and multiplication of numbers

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

so I was writing a program that took two strings and said if they were anagrams or not, and I had this idea of making each character into a number, adding them all and checking if the result was the same.
This doesn't work because the result is not unique, and there are other strings that could have the same value.
Then I moved on to multiplication, and I was faced with the same problem.
I eventually solved the problem, but I was wondering: maybe the pair of the sum and the multiplication of the characters in the string is unique?
I haven't been able to find a counter-example for that, but I haven't been able to prove it either.

Comment: $\{2,8,9\}$ and $\{3,4,12\}$ is an example.

Comment: Hint: you can associate a character to a prime number and use product.

Comment: For strings of $n$ letters, the values of the $n$ [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in $n$ variables will uniquely determine the unordered list of numbers.  So, for example, $a+b$ and $ab$ determine $a$ and $b$, but you need $a+b+c, ab+ac+bc$, and $abc$ to determine $a,b,c$.

Comment: You can also take the Newton sums $S_i = \sum_k a_k^i$ (you need $S_1,\dots,S_n$ if there are $n$ characters).